# Custom Implicit style for WPF Toolkit WatermarkTextBox

Tags: wpf, xceed

From [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/357635) it seems possible to create a custom implicit style for WpfToolkit `IntegerUpDown` control.

```
<Style TargetType="xctk:IntegerUpDown"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type xctk:IntegerUpDown}}">
```

I cannot seem to create a custom implicit style for WpfToolkit `WatermarkTextBox` though. I have tried this but it does not compile:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" ...>

<Style TargetType="xctk:WatermarkTextBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}}">...</Style>
```

Produces error:

> Failed to create a 'TargetType' from the text 'xctk:WatermarkTextBox'

Also tried:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" x:Key="WatermarkBaseStyle">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WatermarkBaseStyle}"/>
```

Produces error:

> 'Failed to create a 'Type' from the text 'xctk:WatermarkTextBox'.'

Comment: Have you tried TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}"?

Comment: Yes, updated question with results.

Comment: And are you able to create an element somewhere in your XAML, like <xctk:WatermarkTextBox />? If so, I'll let someone else look into it, who actually has the sources of the toolkit...

Comment: Yes, and using a named style with `TargetType="{x:Type Control}"` I am able to use a named style. But I am trying to define an implicit style so I don't have to apply the style by name to each control. This works: `<xctk:WatermarkTextBox Style="{DynamicResource WatermarkBaseStyle}"/>`

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type xctk:WatermarkTextBox}}">
```

Try using the `x:Type` markup extension in *both* the `TargetType` and `BasedOn` properties.